# trying to import file in ansible that is provided by @ using -e parameter

Tags: devops

I am running **playbook** with `-e` option and taking a file as variable for example:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -i inventory -e @/tmp/file.yml
```

Now my requirement is to include this file as `vars_file` to be able to override some inventory variables in case the file is defined otherwise the playbook should run normally.

How can i set a fact to capture this variable name. This name can vary and will be provided at runtime by the user

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to conditionally load variables if a filename is given. For that, I would look at the [`include_vars` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html). You can even choose to run the task using that module based on whether a variable is set. See below for an example.

```
- name: Conditionally decide to load in variables
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ extra_vars_file }}"
  when: extra_vars_file | default("") != ""
```

Comment: Actually my scenario is a bit different. I need to pass the file by using @file.yml in extra arguments and then the playbook i have will import these variables and override the group_vars/all.yml and in case this file is not passed it will continue with normal execution.

Comment: no my question is how can i refer to this file for import in my playbook and secondly the file name is also not common this will be dependent on user as many users will be running this playbook

Comment: Hm, I think I'm a little confused then. I think I've answered based even on what you've commented. Can you add a bit more?

To expand on my answer, one of the tasks in the playbook would be what I have shown above when the playbook is executed like this: `ansible-playbook test.yml -e 'extra_vars_file=geowa4.yml'`. If the the `extra_vars_file` value isn't set, it will skip that include. One thing maybe worth adding is a check if the file exists with the stat module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html). The syntax is different but it seems to address your goals.